# How can i complete an algorithm to generate full arrangement?

Tags: c++, recursion

I do know how to use the `std::next_permutation` `<algorithm>` function, but I want to know what happens under the hood, to generate a full arrangement for a string.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    cin >> str;

    cout << str << endl;

    while (next_permutation(str.begin(), str.end())) {
        cout << str << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried but it didn't work. I dont know, but something happens with my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void permute(string str, int l, int r) {
    if (l == r) {
        cout << str << endl;
    } else {
        for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {
            swap(str[l], str[i]);
            permute(str, l + 1, r);
            swap(str[l], str[i]);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    int n = str.size();
    permute(str, 0, n - 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Google thinks a "full arrangement with strings" is something about music. I don't think you are doing music. "it didnt work" and "something happens" are also not very informative. Please explain. What are you trying to achieve, what is an example input, what were you expecting to get and what did you get instead?

Comment: If you are looking for how `next_permutation` works, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation has an example implementation.

Comment: Side note: About [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)…

Comment: Sidenote: Printing all permutations of a string from the point where you start could be simplified by using a `do { ... } while(std::next_permutation(...));` loop instead of printing the first permuation before the `while(...) { ... }` loop. Also note that you miss all the permutations prior to the starting point (lexigographically speaking).

Comment: @user12002570 Good dupe. I just found that one and was about to close for for the same reason too. I don't understand why you both post it as a link in the comments and close the question at the same time though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The main reason for posting the link in the comments(besides closing) is because sometimes the posts get reopened and then the related post get lost(i mean it does anymore show up in the "linked" section on the right hand side). So I also post the link of atleast one dupe/related post in the comments. So it's easier to find all related posts when I search for a dupe next time.

Comment: @user12002570 _"sometimes the posts get reopened"_- Ok, but if that happens, wouldn't that mean that the dupe was rejected by enough people that you wouldn't want the comment there? Hmm, sorry, this should be a "meta" discussion. Anyway, I now understand why you did it.

Comment: Seems that I completed too late (-> @user12002570)... Still here my [demonstration](https://godbolt.org/z/xrrd73qfb), it appears a little simpler to me than the one in the link above. It does essentially the same than `std::next_permutation`, but starts permuting at the front end instead of the back end – decided that way for easier wording.

Comment: To convert to `std::next_permutation` order use the `rbegin` and `rend` reverse iterators instead and compare for less instead of greater. For the comments: swap successor and predecessor, *but* usage of `--`/`++` and `std::prev`/`std::next` need to *remain*, which might appear confusing at a first glance (thus my decision to start at the other end…), but the reverse iterators go in inverse direction, too (++ goes towards front), so we're actually fine.

Comment: @Aconcagua Yeah you should also post your demo link  to the [first](https://godbolt.org/z/xrrd73qfb) as it is the first poso that pops up(showed)  on search engine.

Comment: @user12002570 Too late to edit :( [here](https://godbolt.org/z/65djTYvjG) showing up at first line.